# Sitecore database name change

Tags: sitecore-commerce

When we installed Sitecore Commerce 9, it created databases with names SitecoreCommerce9_Global and SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments...

I would like to change their names.

Please someone tell me the best way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Short steps:

1. shut down IIS
2. Change DB Names in SQL Server
3. modify engine configs

   wwwroot\data\environments\Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json

   wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
4. Start IIS
5. Bootstrap (using Postman or customized SIF step)